# Разместить иконки на одном уровне с текстом

Tags: html, css

Привет, посмотрите пожалуйста мой код, и подскажите, как разместить иконки на одном уровне с текстом?

```css
.about__mission__right{
 float: right;
 width: 411px;
 height: 344px;
}

.icon{
 padding-top: 35px;
}

h4{
 padding-left: 12px;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #4e8598;
}

.light__text{
 padding-left: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #b0b2b3;
}
```

```html
<div class="about__mission__right">
      <h3>О заслугах</h3>
      <img class="icon" src="img/bug.png" alt="">
      <h4>Волшебный жук</h4>
      <p class="light__text">Позволяет быть в тонусе</p>

      <img class="icon" src="img/bell.png" alt="">
      <h4>Волшебный жук</h4>
      <p class="light__text">Позволяет быть в тонусе</p>

      <img class="icon" src="img/storm.png" alt="">
      <h4>Волшебный жук</h4>
      <p class="light__text">Позволяет быть в тонусе</p>

      <img class="icon" src="img/camera.png" alt="">
      <h4>Волшебный жук</h4>
      <p class="light__text">Позволяет быть в тонусе</p>
     </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените на

```
.icon{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов много, это один из вариантов

```
  .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
```

```css
.about__mission__right {
  float: right;
  width: 411px;
  height: 344px;
  background: gray;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

h4 {
  padding-left: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #4e8598;
}

.light__text {
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #b0b2b3;
}
```

```html
<div class="about__mission__right">
  <h3>О заслугах</h3>
  <img class="icon" src="img/bug.png" alt="bug.png">
  <h4>Волшебный жук</h4>
  <p class="light__text">Позволяет быть в тонусе</p>

  <img class="icon" src="img/bell.png" alt="bell.png">
  <h4>Волшебный жук</h4>
  <p class="light__text">Позволяет быть в тонусе</p>

  <img class="icon" src="img/storm.png" alt="storm.png">
  <h4>Волшебный жук</h4>
  <p class="light__text">Позволяет быть в тонусе</p>

  <img class="icon" src="img/camera.png" alt="camera.png">
  <h4>Волшебный жук</h4>
  <p class="light__text">Позволяет быть в тонусе</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем менять inline на inline-block,на свойство veritacal-align: baseline это не повлияет.И судя по картинке требуется middle,что я ниже и указал

Comment: Я вроде указал, что возможностей куча, все зависит от ситуации.

Comment: Ну если автору нужен верхний отступ,тогда да...